# What is the meaning of "-y" in this command

Tags: command-line, execute-command

I don't understand the meaning of `-y`.

command:

```
apt-get install -y clickhouse-client & sudo apt-get install -y passenger
```

There are many commands have `-y`.

Comment: Did you try `man apt-get` in a terminal (or in google) before posting you question here ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `-y` means *Assume **yes** as answer*

i.e. in any case of a question, the program will automatically respond with *yes* as answer.

From [man apt-get](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/apt-get.8)

> **-y, --yes, --assume-yes**
>
> Automatic yes to prompts. Assume "yes" as answer to all prompts and
>   run non-interactively. If an undesirable situation, such as changing a
>   held package or removing an essential package, occurs then apt-get
>   will abort.  Configuration Item: APT::Get::Assume-Yes.